# How do I save an Excel file as CSV using VBA whereby the new file won't give me an error message?

Tags: vba, excel

I know there are similar questions (and answers) on Stack Overflow but I'm specifically trying to prompt the end user to save the file and rename it as appropriate, not have the file automatically created.

I'm trying to create a macro that will automatically export a worksheet in my workbook and save the file for non-technical users, as a CSV. The macro actually works fine, but each file it creates gives me the error message "The file format and extension of 'NAME OF FILE.csv' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?" How can I have this new file open up without this warning message? Here's my code:

```
Sub copy_translated_file()

Dim DstFile As String 'Destination File Name
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim InitFile As String

InitFile = "BE SURE TO CHANGE THE NAME OF THIS FILE TO WHAT YOU WANT.csv"
    Sheets("Translated").Select
    Sheets("Translated").Copy

    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

     Application.CutCopyMode = False

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete 'Get rid of the macro button

    Columns("N:N").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("F1").Select

DstFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitFile, _
                                        fileFilter:="CSV (*.csv), *.csv", _
                                        FilterIndex:=1, _
                                        Title:="Save As")
        If DstFile = "False" Then
            MsgBox "Actions Canceled. File not saved."
            wb.Close savechanges:=False 'Close File
            Exit Sub
        Else
        wb.SaveAs DstFile 'Save file
        wb.Close False 'Close file
        MsgBox ("Translated file successfully saved in specified location.")
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you're saving as a regular Excel format, but with a CSV extension?  See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel   You need to supply the correct `FileFormat` argument.

Answer (score 0):

That is a setting in Excel itself, going to File -> Options -> Trust Center

Also, ensure your flag is set for `FileFormat:=xlCSV`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I actually tried adding a FileFormat flag but get another error: "Compile Error: Named argument no found" when I do so when modifying the GetSaveAsFilename to:  






    DstFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitFile, _
                                            fileFilter:="CSV (*.csv), *.csv", _
                                            FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
                                            FilterIndex:=1, _
                                            Title:="Save As")

Comment: `FileFormat` is an argument to `SaveAs`, not `GetSaveAsFilename`

Comment: @TimWilliams I totally missed that, good catch! May I ask why you're using GetSaveAs? It seems you're trying to save the file not **get** the save file name

Comment: @Maldred I'm trying to create a tool for non-technical end users to save files in CSV format and making it as simple as possible for them...but, it doesn't like like GetSaveAs will work with what I'm trying to do, it doesn't have the argument I need. Thank you both for your input!